# Express js stream and download file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I am trying to stream a file from an s3 location and download the file after streaming

```
     //get the url
    let url = s3Service.getSignedUrl({
            Bucket:process.env.s3BucketName,
            Key:'vault-files/'+filePath,
            Expires:240
           });
           console.log(url);

   //download
       let stream = res.attachment(url);
       stream.pipe(res);
```

I am getting the URL properly but it's not downloading properly

Comment: `res.attachment` does not return a Stream?! What are you trying to do there?

Comment: i want to download the stream as a file

Comment: Do you want to redirect the client to s3 to download it, or do you want to open a connection to s3, and stream the response to the user? If so, the first step would be to find a fitting s3 api that exposes a stream.

Comment: First, I would like to get content from s3 URL and return its as a another file to the user the reason is i can't expose the s3 url directly to the end user.

Comment: As far as i understand its the sense of signed urls to be exposed to the user: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html